# How to redirect a user to another page with a button click using only JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

How to redirect a user to another page on a website using a linked JavaScript file, and how to convert the following line of code to non-embedded, linked JavaScript?

```
<button id="mybutton" type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>
```

HTML:

```
<button id="mybutton" type="button">Click me!</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function goToAnotherPage() {
  window.location.assign("myotherpage.html");
}

function init() {
  document.getElementById("mybutton").onclick = goToAnotherPage();
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting in the console? Side note, missing a quote in `id=mybutton"`

Comment: There's more than one tag with `id="mybutton"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to redirect users:

1. If you want to simulate someone clicking on a link, update the `window.location.href` property
2. If you want to simulate a HTTP redirect, use the `window.location.replace()` function

Create your buttons:

```
<button id="my-button-1">Redirect 1</button>
<button id="my-button-2">Redirect 2</button>
```

Then, instead of using inline events, use event listeners in order to allow event delegation:

```
document.getElementById("my-button-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.replace("redirect/path/for/btn-1.html");
});

document.getElementById("my-button-2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.replace("redirect/path/for/btn-2.html");
});
```

If you want to simulate a link click, use this instead:

```
document.getElementById("my-button-1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.href = "redirect/path/for/btn-1.html";
});

document.getElementById("my-button-2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  window.location.href = "redirect/path/for/btn-2.html";
});
```

**NOTE:** The `window.location.replace(...)` doesn't keep the originating page in the session history, this means that user won't have to click the back button to get back to where they were.

Comment: You mean **event listeners** in order to allow **event delegation**. It is fair to point this out so I don't know why this gets downvoted. Maybe add some HTML so your answer would be more clear.

Comment: @Barrosy Thanks for the heads up, I hadn't seen my mistake.

Comment: You're very welcome, I wish you the best with your project.